# Modsecurity - OWASP CRS 901001

Tags: apache, owasp, mod-security

Ubuntu 18.04
Apache/2.4.29
ModSecurity for Apache/2.9.2 (http://www.modsecurity.org/); OWASP_CRS/3.0.0
modsecurity-crs 3.0.2-1

This is a new server.  The following message appears in `modsec_audit.log` in every entry:

```
--c2d2e910-H--
Message: Warning. Operator EQ matched 0 at TX. [file 
"/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-901-INITIALIZATION.conf"] 
[line "56"] [id "901001"] [msg "ModSecurity Core Rules setup file has 
not been detected. Threat detection and blocking may be nonfunctional. 
Please ensure to make a copy of the setup template crs- 
setup.conf.example, and include your crs-setup.conf file in your 
webserver configuration before including the CRS rules."] [severity 
"WARNING"]
```

```
me@www:~$ apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES |grep security2_module
 security2_module (shared)
```

As shown above, the module is loaded.  My Apache conf has an `<IfModule security2_module>` stanza that includes:

```
IncludeOptional /usr/share/modsecurity-crs/owasp-crs.load
```

The file `owasp-crs.load` has:

```
Include /etc/modsecurity/crs/crs-setup.conf
IncludeOptional /etc/modsecurity/crs/REQUEST-900-EXCLUSION-RULES-BEFORE-CRS.conf
Include /usr/share/modsecurity-crs/rules/*.conf
IncludeOptional /etc/modsecurity/crs/RESPONSE-999-EXCLUSION-RULES-AFTER-CRS.conf
```

```
me@www:~$ ls /etc/modsecurity/crs/crs-setup.conf
/etc/modsecurity/crs/crs-setup.conf
```

As the warning states, `crs-setup.conf` can't be found though the file exists in the specified location.  However, the system seems to be working properly.  For example, in `crs-setup.conf` if I remove all HTTP methods from ID `900200` then I get a HTTP 403 Forbidden which is expected based on how I have the system configured.

Your thoughts and experience are appreciated in helping to resolve this.

Thank you.

Comment: The message concerns `[file 
"/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-901-INITIALIZATION.conf"` while conf samples are `900 / 999` files: where is the 901 located? in `/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/rules/*.conf`? If so, replace the `IncludeOptional` of `900` with `Include` : if error is now on file `900`, then it means the `crs-setup` is indeed not loaded (check the file permissions maybe) and if error is still on `901` then it means the `900` file is breaking the conf defined by `crs-setup.conf` so check `900`'s content

Comment: File `/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-901-INITIALIZATION.conf` exists - that's where the text "ModSecurity Core Rules setup file has not been detected. Threat detection and blocking may be nonfunctional. Please ensure to make a copy of the setup template crs-setup.conf.example, and include your crs-setup.conf file in your webserver configuration before including the CRS rules." comes from in the warning message.  File `/etc/modsecurity/crs/crs-setup.conf` is loaded as noted in my original post.  Further proof of that is if I rename `crs-setup.conf` then Apache fails to restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research and testing I've come to the conclusion that this is a spurious message which can safely be ignored in my situation.  My system is otherwise working as intended and expected.